# parse.com in Swift - is it possible to cast retrieved PFObject as subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've created a subclass of PFObject, basically following instructions on [parse.com docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses), and pinned the object locally. The parse docs don't seem to go into retrieving a PFObject subclass, and I'm wondering - is it possible to cast the retrieved object as the PFObject subclass. If so, how?

(I understand if it's not possible, it could be necessary to re-instantiate the subclass, based on the retrieved properties of the PFObject.)

```
   let query = PFQuery(className:Armor.parseClassName())
    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if let error = error {
            // There was an error
        } else {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    //This println is outputting to the console:
                    println("PFObject object retrieved")
                    if let object = object as? Armor {
                          //This println is NOT outputting to the console:
                          println("PFObject object cast as Armor")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `if object is Armor { ... }`

Comment: `(object is Armor)` is equal to false.

Comment: What Parse library version are you using?

Comment: Did you register subclass in AppDelegare?

Comment: @RaVeN Parse library 1.7.2

Comment: @top.dev See reply to your answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Be sure you've registered subclass in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. In my case, it doesn't cast the retrieved object as the PFObject subclass.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Armor.registerSubclass()

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
    Parse.setApplicationId(..., clientKey: ...)

    return true
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    CatsObject.registerSubclass()

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
    Parse.setApplicationId("...", clientKey: "...")

    return true
}
```

**CatsObject.swift**

```
import Foundation

class CatsObject: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Cat"
    }
}
```

**CatViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    queryData()
}

func queryData() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: CatsObject.parseClassName())
    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if let error = error {
            // There was an error
        } else {
            println("count local objects = \(objects?.count)")
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    println("PFObject object retrieved")
                    if object is CatsObject {
                        println("object is CatsObject subclass")
                    }

                    if let object = object as? CatsObject {
                        println("PFObject object cast as CatsObject")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Console output**

```
count local objects = Optional(10)
PFObject object retrieved
object is CatsObject subclass
PFObject object cast as CatsObject
```

Comment: I am following the instructions and sample code in the subclassing section of the parse.com docs, which calls registerSubclass() in the initialize method. I'm going to give your suggestion a go, of instead registering the subclass in the AppDelegate. When you retrieve your object are you able to cast it as your subclass rather than PFObject?

Comment: I have tested your theory, and you're right. Registering the subclass in the Application delegate seems to work, whereas registering it in the initialise method as per the sample code in the docs does not!

Comment: I'm having a related issue - I'm running into problems adding a custom object to a subclassed PFObject and have added another stack overflow issue. Perhaps you'd like to take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338526/ios-swift-parse-com-possible-to-store-custom-object-in-pfobject-subclass

Comment: Works like a charm! I had an issue that was driving me crazy trying to debug and it ended up being that I had forgotten to register the subclass for a new Parse class I created. Thanks again!